# Can you use .NET Active Directory for authentication from a MAUI Windows Desktop app and is there a code sample?

Tags: c#, active-directory, maui-windows

Has anyone been able to get a MAUI Windows desktop app to work with either .NET Active Directory or Active Directory Federation Services for authentication?

For small companies and even medium size companies operating with tight margins, .NET Active Directory is all they need or can afford.

Blazor Server supported the following code:

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = authState.User;
 
if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    UserId = user.Identity.Name;
}
```

Which made it really easy to work with .NET Windows Active Directory. But, I haven't been able to get that to work in a MAUI Windows Desktop app.  MAUI Blazor Desktop apps have more in common with Blazor Server than MAUI Blazor Mobile apps from security requirements standpoint.

Comment: MAUI is for cross-platform development. Is there a reason you want to use MAUI if your intent is to build a Windows-only app?

Answer (score 0):

MAUI Blazor, since it is cross platform, uses the security of the underlying platform.  So, for Windows it is simply:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    UserId = windowsIdentity.Name;
}
```